# Sending ics file by email, it shows three options as Yes|Maybe|No. I want to get only one button as "Add to calendar"

Tags: icalendar

Sending an email by Laravel application, I am creating and sending an iCalendar event as an attachment. Opening the sent email in Outlook(Office 365) I see three buttons as Yes|Maybe|No. If users clicks on Yes option, it saves the event in her/his calendar. I don't want to have these three buttons. Instead I want a single button as "Add to calendar".

When I change the method from REQUEST to CANCEL, it shows only one button as "Remove from calendar".

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:event.foo.bar
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:e1@ctsi.eve.test
SEQUENCE:1
SUMMARY:Lorem Ipsum
DTSTART:20190418T095700Z
DTEND:20190418T115700Z
DESCRIPTION:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent id sapien nisi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam porttitor nec nulla consectetur interdum.
LOCATION:Toronto, Canada
DTSTAMP:20190411T095811
ATTENDEE;CN=John Doe;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:foo@bar.ca
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be solved by those who know Laravel, so I'm not sure is the Laravel tag is helpful here.

Comment: Thank you @namelivia, I removed the tag.

Answer (score 2):

Bahman,

Use method 'PUBLISH' if you just want them to add it to the calendar.
REQUEST is when you are sending an invitation and requesting their attendance.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-1.4